# How can I compress a char array into a compressed html page using Zlib

Tags: html, gzip, zlib, deflate, http-compression

I have a CGI application in C that creates an html page by saving a char* as a html page:

```
void saveTextFile(const char *filename, const char *str){.......}
```

called as

```
saveTextFile("..\\index.html",outputFile);
```

How do I use zlib to take as **input** the "outputFile" char array and output a zipped html page with appropriate headers?

Would the [gzopen](http://zlib.net/manual.html#gzopen) be used here instead of my saveTextFile function?

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it -

```
//****************************************************************************************
    //ZIP file: Take the char string "outputFile" as input to gzip. Create a zipped html file
    file = gzopen("..\\index.html.gz", "wb"); //create a zipped file
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Can't open zipped file");
        exit(1);
    }
    len   = strlen(outputFile); //need to know length of string
    compd = gzwrite(file, outputFile, (unsigned)len); //compress data into .gz file
    cls   = gzclose (file); //close .gz file
    //End zip***********************************************************************************
```